Creating a `MemberMacro` that creates an embeded struct with injected conformances
I am implementing a MemberMacro in Swift. I was able to implement everything but one requirement.
Here's what I was able to do so far:

create an embedded struct within the class I attach the macro to
this struct has the same properties as the class

So basically this …
@RecordInterfacable
@Observable
class Model {
  let id: UUID
  var title: String
  init(
    id: UUID = UUID(),
    title: String
  ) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
  }
}

results in this:
@Observable
class Model {
  let id: UUID
  var title: String
  init(
    id: UUID = UUID(),
    title: String
  ) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
  }
  // I need to make this struct conform to protocols that I inject at call site of the macro – but how?
  struct ModelRecord: Codable {
    let id: UUID
    var title: String
  }
  init(from record: ModelRecord) {
    init(
      id: record.id,
      title: record.title
    )
  }
  func convertToRecord() -> ModelRecord {
    ModelRecord(
      id: self.id,
      title: self.title
    )
}

Here's what's missing:

I need the struct to conform to specific conformances on demand–meaning that I want to be able to define at call site, what the added, embedded struct conforms to

The function implementing the MemberMacro is static expansion(of:providingMembersOf:conformingTo:in:) has a the property conformingTo.
The documentation for this func has the following to say concerning this property:
conformingTo
The set of protocols that were declared in the set of conformances for the macro and to 
which the declaration does not explicitly conform. The member macro itself cannot declare 
conformances to these protocols (only an extension macro can do that), but can provide 
supporting declarations, such as a required initializer or stored property, that cannot be 
written in an extension.

Here's the thing though: I have not found out how to declare those conformances at callsite.
At callsite, I currently just annotate my class with @@RecordInterfacable-but I have no clue as to how to inject the desired conformances here … Can somebody give me a hint as to how to do this?
Here's the macros implementation:
//RecordInterfacable
@attached(member, names: arbitrary)
public macro RecordInterfacable() = #externalMacro(module: "RecordInterfacableMacros", type: "RecordInterfacableMacro")

//RecordInterfacableMacro
public struct RecordInterfacableMacro: MemberMacro {
  public static func expansion(
    of node: AttributeSyntax,
    providingMembersOf declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax,
    conformingTo protocols: [TypeSyntax],
    in context: some MacroExpansionContext
  ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
    let classDecl = try assertClassDecl(for: declaration)
    let symbolName = try extractSymbolName(from: classDecl)

    /// Extracts all the elements of the body of the given class.
    /// This includes all properties and functions.
    let membersDeclSyntax = declaration
      .as(ClassDeclSyntax.self)?
      .memberBlock
      .members
      .compactMap {
        $0
          .as(MemberBlockItemSyntax.self)?
          .decl
          .as(DeclSyntax.self)
      }

    /// Further extracts all variables
    let membersVariableDeclSyntax = membersDeclSyntax?
      .compactMap {
        $0
          .as(VariableDeclSyntax.self)
      }


    let memberBindingSpecifiers: [String]? = membersVariableDeclSyntax?
      .compactMap { member in
        guard let memberBindingSpecifier = member
          .bindingSpecifier
          .text
          .split(separator: ".")
          .last
        else { fatalError() }
        return "\(memberBindingSpecifier)"
      }
    guard let memberBindingSpecifiers else { fatalError() }

    /// Create a string with the declaration of all members
    let identifierTexts = membersVariableDeclSyntax?
      .map { member in
        let identifierText = member
          .bindings
          .compactMap {
            $0
              .as(PatternBindingSyntax.self)?
              .pattern
              .as(IdentifierPatternSyntax.self)?
              .identifier
              .text
          }
          .first
        guard let identifierText else { fatalError() }
        return identifierText
      }
    guard let identifierTexts
    else { fatalError() }

    let memberTypes = membersVariableDeclSyntax?
      .map { member in
        let memberType = member
          .bindings
          .compactMap {
            $0
              .as(PatternBindingSyntax.self)?
              .typeAnnotation?
              .type
              .as(IdentifierTypeSyntax.self)?
              .name
              .text
          }
          .first
        guard let memberType else { fatalError() }
        return memberType
      }
    guard let memberTypes
    else { fatalError() }

    var memberStrings = [String]()
    var initStrings = [String]()
    var varString = [String]()
    for i in 0..<identifierTexts.count {
      memberStrings.append("\(memberBindingSpecifiers[i]) \(identifierTexts[i]): \(memberTypes[i])")
      initStrings.append("\(identifierTexts[i]): record.\(identifierTexts[i])")
      varString.append("\(identifierTexts[i]): self.\(identifierTexts[i])")
    }
    let memberString = memberStrings
      .joined(separator: "\n")
    let initString = initStrings
      .joined(separator: ", ")

    return [
      DeclSyntax(
        stringLiteral: """
        struct \(symbolName)Record: Codable, FetchableRecord, PersistableRecord {
          \(memberString)
        }
        """
      ),
      DeclSyntax(
        extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral: """
      convenience init(from record: \(symbolName)Record) {
        self.init(\(initString))
      }
      """
      ),
      DeclSyntax(
        stringLiteral: """
      var record: \(symbolName)Record {
        \(symbolName)Record(id: self.id, title: self.title)
      }
      """
      ),
    ]
  }
}


I don't think the conformingTo parameter is helpful here. Unfortunately, the documentation for macros is not very good, but I recently had a similar problem and found this swift evolution proposal which explains it a bit better: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0407-member-macro-conformances.md . I think your best option is to write separate extension macros for the conformances, and inject them as arguments to your macro attribute.

I think a possible solution is to create separate extension macros that implement the conformances (which have replaced the deprecated "conformance" macros), and then pass the types you want to conform to as arguments to your RecordableInterface macro.
For example, if you want to make the inner struct conform to Hashable, you would write an extension macro that can do that. I won't include the implementation here, as how to make an extension macro is a bit out of scope, but the macro declaration might look like this:
@attached(extension, conformances: Hashable)
public macro InnerHashable() = #externalMacro(module: "MacroImplementations", type: "InnerHashableMacro")

Next, update the declaration of your RecordInterfaceable macro:
@attached(member, names: arbitrary)
public macro RecordInterfaceable(conformances: Any.Type...) = #externalMacro(module: "MacroExamplesImplementation", type: "RecordInterfaceableMacro")

Now in the macro implementation you can access the list of arguments with the node parameter. You can then check which types were passed in and select the appropriate macro to add to the generated nested type. Here's a truncated example:
public struct RecordInterfacableMacro: MemberMacro {
  public static func expansion(
    of node: AttributeSyntax,
    providingMembersOf declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax,
    conformingTo protocols: [TypeSyntax],
    in context: some MacroExpansionContext
  ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
    guard let args = node.arguments?.as(LabeledExprListSyntax.self) else {
        return []
    }

    let attributes = try args.compactMap { labeledExpr in
        guard let declBase = labeledExpr
            .expression.as(MemberAccessExprSyntax.self)?
            .base?.as(DeclReferenceExprSyntax.self)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        
        //Handle as many possible macros as needed.
        if declBase == "Hashable" {
            return "@InnerHashable"
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    let innerAttribs = attributes.joined("\n")

    ...

    return [
      DeclSyntax(
        stringLiteral: """
        \(raw: innerAttribs)
        struct \(symbolName)Record: Codable, FetchableRecord, PersistableRecord {
          \(memberString)
        }
        """
      ),
      DeclSyntax(
        extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral: """
      convenience init(from record: \(symbolName)Record) {
        self.init(\(initString))
      }
      """
      ),
      DeclSyntax(
        stringLiteral: """
      var record: \(symbolName)Record {
        \(symbolName)Record(id: self.id, title: self.title)
      }
      """
      ),
    ]
  }
}

I haven't actually tested this code, so I'm sure there are details that will need to be worked out, but I think this general process will achieve what you're trying to do.

It's a little bit simpler than that for my needs, but your answer certainly did help me understand how I can use the macros arguments to actually achieve what I wanted–so thanks a lot for that! I just need to join the list of protocol types and make the struct conform to those additionally.

Getting to the arguments looks something like this now: let conformances = node.arguments?.as(LabeledExprListSyntax.self)?.compactMap { $0.expression.as(ExprSyntax.self)?.as(DeclReferenceExprSyntax.self)?.baseName.text }
let conformanceString = conformances?.joined(separator: ", ")

And attaching it to the struct DeclSyntax is this: struct \(symbolName)Record: Codable\((conformanceString?.isEmpty ?? true) ? "" : ",\(conformanceString!)") { }

I think it's best to mark your answer as correct anyways cause it got me to where I wanted to be–anyone else stumbling over this thread: you can find the current version of the whole implementation to be referenced over here on GitHub.

Glad it pointed you in the right direction! I suspected there would be some issues because it’s a bit of a nuisance to quickly set up a macro package and test this out, so I was basically copy-pasting from my own project and doing stuff from memory. Feel free to edit my code with the fixes.
